# .Net Print PowerPoint Document using Office interops

Tags: .net, printing, powerpoint

I'm working on a small project which can print office docs with some printer options.

The MS Word interop worked good with the word docs, but when I tried something similar to it using the powerpoint interop, it does not work.

My code for printing Word docs, 4pages on one paper using zoom.

```
public void test5()
    {
        try
        {
            // Declaring the object variables we will need later
            object varFileName = filePath;
            object varFalseValue = false;
            object varTrueValue = true;
            object varMissing = Type.Missing;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application varWord =
                new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application varPPT = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document varDoc =
           varWord.Documents.Open(ref varFileName, ref varMissing,
              true,
              ref varMissing, ref varMissing, ref varMissing, ref varMissing,
              ref varMissing, ref varMissing, ref varMissing,
              ref varMissing, ref varMissing, ref varMissing, ref varMissing,
              ref varMissing, ref varMissing);

            varDoc.Activate();
            varDoc.PrintOut(PrintZoomColumn: 2, PrintZoomRow: 2);

           }
        catch (Exception varE)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Error:\n" + varE.Message, "Error message");
        }
    }
```

Quite simple. What I need to do is to add PrintZoomColumn, PrintZoomRow options on the PrintOut method. But, according to the MSDN, the PowerPoint lacks such options. Neither PrintZoomColunm nor PrintZoomRow even exists. However, I found a method called PrintOptions under the Presentation class, but this is not showing any effect.

Here's my code for printing PPT files.

```
public void test6()
    {
        try
        {
            // Declaring the object variables we will need later
            object varFileName = filePath;
            object varFalseValue = false;
            object varTrueValue = true;
            object varMissing = Type.Missing;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application varPPT = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation varPre = varPPT.Presentations.Open(filePath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
            varPre.PrintOptions.HandoutOrder =Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintHandoutOrder.ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst;
            varPre.PrintOut();
        }
        catch (Exception varE)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:\n" + varE.Message, "Error message");
        }
    }
```

On the above code, changing the value of handoutorder of the printoptions does not show any effect. What should I need to print multiple slides on one page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the OutputType property as well. HandoutOrder just tells powerpoint how to lay out the slides on the page **if** there are multiple slides in one page

```
presentation.PrintOptions.OutputType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType.ppPrintOutputFourSlideHandouts;
```

Should give you 4 slides per page